# should there be a statute of limitations for duplicate-hunting?

Tags: feature-request

Let questions have a "pending duplicate-hunting" status that would expire, say, a week after the question is posted. If anybody thinks its a duplicate after that, he/she would just have to forever hold their peace.

Answer (score 9):

About expiry of close votes and pending, This is a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). You will find that there is a section with most votes in [tools](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tools) section. Check on close tab. This is present in [Meta site](/tools)  also.

A question can be closed as a duplicate if five users vote to close. If it doesn't receive five votes, the number of close votes begin to expire.

There should not be a time limit when users can cast a close vote. If there is such feature, a duplicate question will receive many answers (already if a question is not closed quickly, some users without a privilege of review queue post answers. [There are 480 questions as of now](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+answers%3A1). Users with priveleges should act fast). If it's a week, then questions will be filled with many answers. Closing a question after that is pointless. The reason behind duplicate closure is avoiding repetition of questions and answers. Hence, this feature is not useful.